# How can I cancel a Merge in TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoisegit

I must be missing something.

I am a git Newbie.  I unintentionally created a Branch when I did a Switch/Checkout on a single file (reverting to a previous version).

[image]

I then tried to Merge that right branch. But files were in Conflict, so I cancelled.
Now, everytime I try Commit or Switch I get an error that "did not exit cleanly" but when I try to Commit I get the Conflicted Merge.

[image]

How can I cancel the request for the Merge?

Answer (score 6):

You have two choices:

1. Go to the log dialog and perform a hard reset (on the latest revision of your branch)
2. Open the context menu in explorer and select "Abort merge" which basically does the same.

Both options will reset all files in the working tree and the index "back" to the latest version of your current branch.

*Update:* Starting with TortoiseGit 2.4.5 you can also select "git reset --merge" in the "Abort merge" dialog. This option resets the index and tries to restore the pre-merge state of the repository.